# Resharper Attributes in Different Lines

Tags: visual-studio, attributes, resharper, line-breaks

i'm trying to configure it to do this way:

"Before"

```
[Att1(P1 = 10)]
[Att2]
[MyMethodOrProperty]
```

"After"

```
[Att1(P1 = 10), Att2]
[MyMethodOrProperty]
```

"but i want"

```
[Att1(P1 = 10)]
[Att2]
[MyMethodOrProperty]
```

I dont want to put attributes on same line, i want to remain the same. Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproduce. Do you use other extensions in addition to ReSharper? May be StyleCop?

Comment: Please, describe which action did you invoke? Was it some menu item, keyboard shortcut, code cleanup or some quick fix?

Answer (score 2):

This setting is in the ReSharper options. In ReSharper 7.1.3, it is under Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Other, and make sure "Join or separate attributes in section" is set to "Separate".